# Set up proxy server with multiple targets?

Tags: express, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I have 2 express servers:

1. **api1**
2. **api2**

Both are accessed locally using:

`http://localhost:3000/news`

`http://localhost:3001/stock`

***My aim:***

Access both express servers endpoints from a Proxy server on `http://localhost:8008`

***My Issue:***

I can only hit the first **api1**'s endpoints

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const api1 = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'http://localhost:3000'
});


const api2 = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:3001'
  });

const app = express();

app.use(api1);
app.use(api2);

app.listen(8008);
```

**edit1:

I tried this out, which works for **api1** endpoints but not **api2** endpoints.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
const apiProxytwo = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3001'
});

const app = express();

app.use(apiProxy,apiProxytwo);
app.listen(8008);
```

Still looking for a solution!!@! Help please!

Edit 2: Working solution

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();


app.use('/news/*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3000', changeOrigin: true ,}));
app.use('/stock/', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3001', changeOrigin: true, }));

app.listen(8008);
```

Edit 3(*bonus): Applying solution in container setup - have to change localhost to container names(***news*** and ***stock***) for proxy to work with containers correctly.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();


app.use('/news/*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://news:3000', changeOrigin: true ,}));
app.use('/stock/', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://stock:3001', changeOrigin: true, }));

app.listen(8008);
```

Comment: You should add a path for each api. Currently, you are not adding a path and it must be adding both api to root path `/` which is why one api is accessible and the other is not. Try: `app.use('/api1', api1); ` and `app.use('/api2', api2);`.

Comment: hello, I made changes as suggested. Still not working

Comment: So what happens when you send a request to `http://localhost:8008/api1` and `http://localhost:8008/api2`? Which one is accessible and which one is not?

Comment: I get ```Cannot GET /api2```

when I try `http://localhost:8008/api2/stock` I get ```Cannot GET /api2/stock```

Comment: same applies to ```api1```

Comment: I did this, which gets the first api endpoints to work, but not the second

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3001'
});
const apiProxytwo = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

const app = express();

app.use(apiProxy,apiProxytwo);
app.listen(8008);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proxy.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();


app.use('/news/*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3000', changeOrigin: true }));
app.use('/stock', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3001', changeOrigin: true }));

app.listen(8008);
```

newsServer.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/news/headlines', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello from headlines')
});

app.get('/news/other', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello from other')
})


app.listen(3000);
```

query http://localhost:8008/news/headlines => 'hello from headlines'

stockServer.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/stock', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello from api2');
  });


app.listen(3001);
```

query http://localhost:8008/stock => 'hello from api2'

Comment: Hi maxi, thank you for your response.

I am trying to avoid doing it like that as I will have to edit 400+ endpoints manually

all the ***news*** and ***stock*** endpoints  have a second parts to them for example ```/news/headlines```

any thoughts?

Comment: previously execute `node newsServer.js` and `node stockServer.js`

Comment: thank you,

I couldn't get your proxy to work 100%

So I ended up changing all the endpoint names for one of the express servers.

const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/api/v1', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3000',
  logLevel: 'debug'
});
const apiProxytwo = createProxyMiddleware('/', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3001',
  logLevel: 'debug',

});

const app = express();


app.use(apiProxy,apiProxytwo);
app.listen(8008);

Thank you for your help Maxi!

Comment: @cgd it's a shame, you just had to change from `'/news'` to `'/news/*'` in proxy.js to be able to scale your routes

Comment: Hi Maxi - gave it go - and it works!

A thousand thank you's  :)

Comment: @cgd very good! Could you accept my answer as your solution please?

Answer (score 2):

Non of the proposed solutions worked in my case. However upon careful inspection of [http-proxy-middleware options](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options) documentation the only way to change targets based on path, host and any other custom case is using the router option

Therefore this:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();


app.use('/news/*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3000', changeOrigin: true }));
app.use('/stock', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:3001', changeOrigin: true }));

app.listen(8008);
```

would be:

```
app.use("**", createProxyMiddleware({
  target: "http://localhost",
  router:{
    "/news":"http://localhost:3000",
    "/stock":"http://localhost:3001"
  }
}));
```

See: [http-proxy-middleware options](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options)

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const hosts=require("./hosts.json");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
for(var i=0;i<hosts.length;i++){


    app.use(`/${hosts[i].url_key}`, createProxyMiddleware({ target: `${hosts[i].host}`, changeOrigin: true }));
console.log(`/${hosts[i].url_key}`);
}


app.listen(9993);
```

hosts.json:

```
[            {         "host":"https://123456.com",         "url_key":"123456/*"            },     
  {         "host":"https://1234567.com",         "url_key":"yourkey/*"            },
]
```

I Hope it helps...